# EKS ingress resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm trying to configure an Ingress resource in an EKS cluster running v1.18 using the below configuration.  after running `kubectl apply -f blah.yaml` I'm returned `error: unable to recognize "blah.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" inversion "networking.k8s.io/v1"` I think it's an apiversion mismatch.  What am I missing?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /boom
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: foo
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what is the apiVersions are present for `networking.k8s.io` resource in your system using

```
kubectl api-versions  | grep networking.k8s.io
```

Check if you have `networking.k8s.io/v1` in the output.

Comment: For us, windows people `kubectl api-versions  | Select-String networking.k8s.io.`

Answer (score 1):

It was a version problem the below works.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /boom
        backend:
          serviceName: foo
          servicePort: 80
```